# Hide everything inside label except img

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

### I want to hide everything inside label except image.

```css
.payment_method_vipps label :not(img){
 display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_vipps">
<input id="payment_method_vipps" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="vipps" data-order_button_text="Betal med Vipps">
 <label for="payment_method_vipps">
   vipps
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Vipps" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
 </label>
<div class="payment_box payment_method_vipps" style="display: block;">
</div>
</li>
```

I have already tried to use the `:not` selector but it hides either everything or nothing. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Main aim is to hide text "vipps". I can not remove text or add any class or id to image thus the code is generated by Wordpress.

Comment: you can search the file in woocommerce, copy in your theme and edit it. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this option is a bit tricky but can work

```
label[for=payment_method_vipps] {font-size:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. It does not seem to work for me. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8IRWK9EVLHG

Comment: check the font size way

Comment: ya you can use this trick with line height 0 or set text color same as background or transparent

Answer (score 0):

Since the `img` is a child of `label[for="payment_method_vipps"]`, everything that hides the label will also hide its contents (i.e. the image). So it probably won't be possible with this HTML structure.

The one thing you can try it to set the label (text) color to `transparent`:

```css
label[for="payment_method_vipps"] {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_vipps">
  <input id="payment_method_vipps" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="vipps" data-order_button_text="Betal med Vipps">
  <label for="payment_method_vipps">
   vipps
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Vipps" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
 </label>
  <div class="payment_box payment_method_vipps" style="display: block;">
  </div>
</li>
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you'd have to wrap the text ("vipps") into a `span` to which you can apply `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. First hide the label and all of its content. Then set the `visibility` of the image to `visible`.
Perhaps it's not the best practice to place the `img` inside the `label` tag. You could nest the text into an `span` tag.

```css
.payment_method_vipps label{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.payment_method_vipps label img{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_vipps">
<input id="payment_method_vipps" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="vipps" data-order_button_text="Betal med Vipps">
 <label for="payment_method_vipps">
   vipps
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Vipps" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
 </label>
<div class="payment_box payment_method_vipps" style="display: block;">
</div>
</li>
```